# My client frequently asks me for Zoom meetings over a project. How do I deal with him?

Tags: difficult-client, project-management, time-management

I have a client who is frequently asking me to conduct Zoom meetings for a very low-budget project which is under progress. Before starting the project, I wasn't aware that he will be asking for multiple meetings like this, and hence I didn't mention "meetings" anywhere in my project agreement with him.

But now, I feel like he is asking too much, and spending too much of my time.

The project has already been delayed by the client. It was supposed to complete within a week, but now it is about to become a month, just because the client is not providing me information and making me wait. Then, he falsely promised that he will give me more work, and that is why I reduced the project price, but he hasn't given more work. And now, he is demanding me for multiple meetings.

I have already spent 1 hour in two Zoom meetings with him. He is asking to meet again and again. Whenever I am asking him for updates, he is asking me to meet on Zoom.

How do I deal with him? Please help.

Comment: I would terminate this project. It is a waste of time and doesn‘t seem to have a future.

Comment: @MS-SPO I think you are right. Thank you so much for your advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ask him immediate payment of what has already been done and announce him the fee for an hour of meeting.

Comment: Thanks! I will do that now. Thank you for your suggestion.